# Rasa stack commands

Tags: python-3.x, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I have got an error , error: unrecognized arguments: \ , while running below commands in Rasa stack bot bulding.

```
 python -m rasa_core.run -d models/dialogue -u models/nlu/current \
          --port 5002 --credentials credentials.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

`\` is used on Linux terminals to break up a command in multiple lines, e.g.:

```
copy file1.txt \
     file2.txt
```

It seems that your terminal does not recognise `\` properly. Are you using Windows as operating system?

On Windows you have to use `^` to break it in multiple lines, e.g `copy file1.txt file2.txt` becomes:

```
copy ^
file1.txt ^ 
file2.txt
```

If this also does not work you can also remove the `\` and have the command in one line:

```
python -m rasa_core.run -d models/dialogue -u models/nlu/current --port 5002 --credentials credentials.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

`\` is used as notation for continuation of a command in Linux. Usually used when the command is very long, so that command is readable. In windows, you can execute without the `\` character, it should work